# how to remove this white ovale behind the focused in the Material Bottom Tabs Navigator

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

Using `@react-navigation/material-bottom-tabs`
and following this [doc](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/material-bottom-tab-navigator)

I wonder how can I remove this weird white round behind the active tab icon?

[image]

Its been 2hours I am trying everything. I am missing something

(nb: I am using the same code of the exemple in the doc, if you want to reproduce, with react-native 0.70.6, I had not this problem on the v 0.68.1 )

EDIT: also with `shifting={true}` when I click on the tab:
[image]

Comment: Even if you're using the exact same code as the doc, please paste the code you're using - if the docs change, the question might be impossible to reproduce.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To "remove" the tab icon, we can set its color to transparent. However, there is no direct way to manipulate the tab icon's color within `@react-navigation/material-bottom-tabs`.

`@react-navigation/material-bottom-tabs` is a wrapper of `BottomNavigation` in `react-native-paper`. Thus, the issue is with `react-native-paper`. This [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74089207/how-to-change-react-native-paper-bottom-navigation-active-color) addresses the exact problem. We need to make changes to the theme, where the tab icon's color can be controlled.

However, according to the [doc](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/material-bottom-tab-navigator/#using-with-react-native-paper-optional), theme from `react-native-paper` cannot be directly applied to react navigation. We have to use `Provider` from `react-native-paper` and apply the theme to the `Provider`.

See the sample code and effect below.

[image]

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import {Text, View} from 'react-native';
import {
  NavigationContainer,
  useNavigationContainerRef,
} from '@react-navigation/native';
import {createMaterialBottomTabNavigator} from '@react-navigation/material-bottom-tabs';
import MaterialCommunityIcons from 'react-native-vector-icons/MaterialCommunityIcons';
import {DefaultTheme, Provider} from 'react-native-paper';

const Tab = createMaterialBottomTabNavigator();

function HomeScreen() {
  return (
    <View style={{flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center'}}>
      <Text>Home!</Text>
    </View>
  );
}

function ProfileScreen() {
  return (
    <View style={{flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center'}}>
      <Text>Profile!</Text>
    </View>
  );
}

function SettingsScreen() {
  return (
    <View style={{flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center'}}>
      <Text>Settings!</Text>
    </View>
  );
}

const App = () => {
  const barColors = {
    home: 'aqua',
    settings: 'gold',
    profile: 'lawngreen',
  };

  const [tab, setTab] = React.useState<keyof typeof barColors>('home');
  const navRef = useNavigationContainerRef();

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = navRef.addListener('state', () => {
      const currRoute = navRef.getCurrentRoute();
      if (currRoute) {
        // A work-around to set background color for the bar after the ripple
        // effect completes. The 200 ms delay comes from trial and error
        setTimeout(() => setTab(currRoute.name as keyof typeof barColors), 200);
      }
    });
    return unsubscribe;
  });

  return (
    <NavigationContainer ref={navRef}>
      <Tab.Navigator
        initialRouteName="home"
        shifting={true}
        activeColor="#e91e63"
        barStyle={{
          backgroundColor: barColors[tab],
        }}>
        <Tab.Screen
          name="home"
          component={HomeScreen}
          options={{
            tabBarColor: barColors.home,
            tabBarLabel: 'Home',
            tabBarIcon: ({color}) => (
              <MaterialCommunityIcons name="home" color={color} size={26} />
            ),
          }}
        />
        <Tab.Screen
          name="settings"
          component={SettingsScreen}
          options={{
            tabBarColor: barColors.settings,
            tabBarLabel: 'Settings',
            tabBarIcon: ({color}) => (
              <MaterialCommunityIcons name="cog" color={color} size={26} />
            ),
          }}
        />
        <Tab.Screen
          name="profile"
          component={ProfileScreen}
          options={{
            tabBarColor: barColors.profile,
            tabBarLabel: 'Profile',
            tabBarIcon: ({color}) => (
              <MaterialCommunityIcons name="account" color={color} size={26} />
            ),
          }}
        />
      </Tab.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
};

const theme = {
  ...DefaultTheme,
  colors: {
    ...DefaultTheme.colors,
    secondaryContainer: 'transparent', // Use transparent to disable the little highlighting oval
  },
};

export default function Main() {
  return (
    <Provider theme={theme}>
      <App />
    </Provider>
  );
}
```

Comment: You are my hero ! 
But I have a new problem, because i am using the shifting={true} with another color, when I click on the tab, I still see this ovale (for a short time) . Any idea ?
I edited my post with the screen for the example

Comment: Quick answer is to set `secondaryContainer: 'transparent'`, which actually resolves all of the issues with that little icon. I have also updated the answer and offered an example of rippling effect.

Answer (score 0):

Based on Fanchen Bao solution:


I couldn't trigger the useEffect cleanup (thus doesn't have access to the navigation and the current state). I found a possible alternative using the NavigatorContainer onStateChange prop and the state.index. The numbers depend on the order that you display the Tab.Screens.

Here's a docs reference about index (https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-state/#partial-state-objects) :

> This also applies to the index property: `index should be the last route in a stack,` and if a different value was specified, React Navigation fixes it.

It is not necessary the useNavigationContainerRef and useEffect for this case. I only copy the part I've added or changed:

I edit my answer since I've just tested it and it's also possible to use the NavigatorContainer theme prop and avoid the use of the Provider.

```js
export default function App() {

// The numbers depends on the order that you display the Tab.Screens on the Tab.Navigator
const barColors = {
    // Tab.Screen home
    0: 'aqua',  
    // Tab.Screen settings
    1: 'gold',
    // Tab.Screen profile
    2: 'lawngreen',
  };

const [tab, setTab] = useState(0);

const stateChanger = (state) => {
  setTab(state.index)
}

const theme = {
      ...DefaultTheme,
      colors: {
        ...DefaultTheme.colors,
        secondaryContainer: 'transparent', // Use transparent to disable the little highlighting oval
      },
    };

return (
    <NavigationContainer  
        onStateChange={stateChanger}
        theme={theme}
    >
```